# Naming query ouput columns using a separate query T-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, naming

Im looking for a way to name columns using the top 1 selection from a separate query.

```
select
   case when t.test=1 then 1 else 0 end  as select top 1 name from #names,
   case when t.test=2 then 1 else 0 end  as select top 1 name from #names2
from table t
```

In this example I want to name then columns by the top selection from several temporary columns. However this does not work. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make this work?

Thank you in advance,
Philip

Comment: This would have to be dynamic SQL - any particular SQL query always returns a result set with the same "shape" - the number of columns, their names and types are all fixed.

Comment: *only* with dynamic sql ... would you share your requirement? how is the  resultset processed? you may be better off renaming columns once you have them in a dataset in an application layer.

Comment: Only with dynamic query can you do that. but a **better** approach can be to return both columns and let your application handle it

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query engine does not evaluate expressions when it expects a column name or alias (any object identifier is expected to be literal).

You can construct your `SELECT` as a string where you inject the names from subqueries:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

set @stmt='
    select
        case when t.test=1 then 1 else 0 end as ['+(select top 1 name from #names)+'],
        case when t.test=2 then 1 else 0 end as ['+(select top 1 name from #names2)+']
    from table t'

exec(@stmt)
```

**Security concern**
As the word "inject" already implies, this can be vulnerable to injection attacks. Use with caution, and only if you have control over the contents of the `#names` and `#names2` tables - do not use this approach when those tables can contain user input.